# How to find similar values in one column with postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I’m a complete newbie in SQL and therefore I’m not very familiar with its functionality.
So here is my problem.
I have the following table with >100.000 companies (let's call it 'comp'):

```
id  | title               | name
----+---------------------+--------------
1   | XYZ                 | xyz
----+---------------------+--------------
2   | Smarts              | smarts
----+---------------------+--------------
3   | XYZ LTD             | xyzltd
----+---------------------+--------------
4   | Outsmarts           | outsmarts
----+---------------------+--------------
5   | XYZ Entertainment   | xyzentertainment
----+---------------------+--------------
6   | Smarts Entertainment| smartsentertainment
```

where 'title' is a company name and 'name' is the same title but low cased and without spaces.
Is there a way to find all companies with similar titles (using either 'title' or 'name')? So, basically, I want to receive:

```
id  | title               | name
----+---------------------+--------------
1   | XYZ                 | xyz
----+---------------------+--------------
3   | XYZ LTD             | xyzltd
----+---------------------+--------------
5   | XYZ Entertainment   | xyzentertainment
----+---------------------+--------------
2   | Smarts              | smarts
----+---------------------+--------------
6   | Smarts Entertainment| smartsentertainment
```

By similar I mean: 
1) 'XYZ', 'XYZ LTD' and 'XYZ Entertainment' 
2) 'Smart' and 'Smart Entertainment' 
but 'XYZ Entertainment' is not similar to 'Smart Entertainment' and 'Smart' is not similar to 'Outsmarts'.

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
SELECT set_limit(0.8);

SELECT
  similarity(c1.name, c2.name) AS sim,
  c1.name,
  c2.name
FROM comp AS c1
  JOIN comp AS c2
    ON c1.name != c2.name
       AND c1.name % c2.name
ORDER BY sim DESC;
```

by 'didn't work' I mean that after 7 minutes it still didn't give me any results. I assume, I totally messed it up 
Is it even possible to retrieve such similarities?

Comment: IN your example, the similar values correspond to the same row. Do you need also to find two similar values in different rows?

Comment: this is practically a cross join on a 100k table. Expect it to be awfully slow. But please do post the explain output

Comment: @FDavidov I have updated the question

Comment: OK, ok.... Let put aside for the moment how you phrase the SELECT command. The task requires to perform 100,000 * 99,999 string comparisons, 9.999 billion comparisons. How much time do you expect this to take? Let's assume that your server can perform 10,000 such comparisons/sec, you would still need to way about 11.5 hours. Simply make the maths before continuing searching for a solution.

Comment: @FDavidov, yeah, I understand this. I'm asking whether it's even possible. If it is possible, maybe there is more elegant and obvious solution)

Comment: Not that I can think of, and I'm pretty sure the chances to find one are extremely slim (if not null). See? I assumed 10,000 comparisons/sec since a single comparison is not checking `a=b?` but much more complex (no need to explain why). The main question would be: Is it something you need to do routinely or only once? If routinely... God help you. If only once, you need to decide if waiting for hours is worth. By the way, once you have it done, every time you add a new business the search becomes 100,000 times faster.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [Levenshtein distance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) function, which gives you the number of edits to achieve the second from the first parameter:

```
SELECT levenshtein(c1.name, c2.name) AS sim, 0c1.name, c2.name
FROM comp AS c1 JOIN comp AS c2 ON c1.name != c2.name ORDER BY sim DESC;
```

Comment: thank you for your response but it also fails. I run this and it just loads my database and doesn't give any results:
`SELECT
  levenshtein(c1.name, c2.name) AS sim,
  c1.name,
  c2.name
FROM comp AS c1
  JOIN comp AS c2 ON c1.name != c2.name
ORDER BY sim DESC; ` 
I might be blind but where is the mistake? Maybe I should check 'title', not 'name?

Comment: Yes, `title` should be better. I just copied and modified your statement from your first post.